# How to retrieve the cropped image after using croppie to crop an image upload

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, croppie

I have searched the documentation which doesn't give away a great deal and have found several people with the same unresolved issue. I have been trying to use croppie to crop uploaded images, before actual upload. The cropping function all works fine but it is the uncropped original version that is being uploaded. I have since learned that I need to retrieve the cropped version somehow as it isn't added to the form. It is converted to base64, which I have assigned to a variable but I have no idea how to add it to the form data. Any help would be amazing as always.

```
$('#cropImageBtn').on('click', function (ev) {
    $uploadCrop.croppie('result', {
        type: 'base64',
        format: 'jpeg',
        size: { width: 300, height: 400 }
    }).then(function (resp) {
        $('#item-img-output').attr('src', resp);
        $('#cropImagePop').modal('hide');
        var form = document.getElementById("add-event-form");

        var ImageURL = resp // Split the base64 string in data and contentType
        alert(ImageURL);
        var block = ImageURL.split(";");
        // Get the content type of the image
        var contentType = block[0].split(":")[1];// In this case "image/gif"
        // get the real base64 content of the file
        var realData = block[1].split(",")[1];// In this case "R0lGODlhPQBEAPeoAJosM...."

        // Convert it to a blob to upload
        var blob = b64toBlob(realData, contentType);

        // Create a FormData and append the file with "image" as parameter name
        var formDataToUpload = new FormData(form);
        formDataToUpload.append("image1", blob);
        return ImageURL;
    });
});
                // End upload preview image
function b64toBlob(b64Data, contentType, sliceSize) {
    contentType = contentType || '';
    sliceSize = sliceSize || 512;

    var byteCharacters = atob(b64Data);
    var byteArrays = [];

    for (var offset = 0; offset < byteCharacters.length; offset += sliceSize) {
        var slice = byteCharacters.slice(offset, offset + sliceSize);

        var byteNumbers = new Array(slice.length);
        for (var i = 0; i < slice.length; i++) {
            byteNumbers[i] = slice.charCodeAt(i);
        }

        var byteArray = new Uint8Array(byteNumbers);

        byteArrays.push(byteArray);
    }

    var blob = new Blob(byteArrays, { type: contentType });
    return blob;
}
```

I have managed to find the data I need and saved it to ImageUrl, but I need to attach this as data to #add-event-form. Please help!

Comment: add to the form an hidden input and assign the base64 value to that input. Easy to do with $().val();

Comment: Thanks a lot, it was simple enough to do that to get the base64 value. Now just to save it!

Comment: you can save it as base64 in the database and decode it when retrieving it back to the frontend

Comment: thats a really good idea i may well try that.